# Will this function be odd?

Tags: functions, inverse

> **Question:** If $f:R\to R$ is an invertible function such that $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ are symmetric about the line $y = -x$, then:
>
> A) $f(x)$ is odd
>
> B) $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ may not be symmetric about $y = x$
>
> C) $f(x)$ may not be odd
>
> D) None of these

Purely by intuition, I'd say that $f(x)$ will be an odd function. Is this right? If it is, how can I prove this?

Comment: $f$ can be not-odd, consider $f(x) = \begin{cases} 2x & x > 0\\ \frac12 x & x \le 0\end{cases}$.

Comment: @kennytm Any more solid proof? I mean it's difficult to think of such a function this quickly.. At least for me.