# Odd and even function

Tags: functions

> If $R→R$ is an invertible function such that $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}$(x) are symmetric about the line $y=−x$,then  
>   (a)$ f(x)$ is odd 
>   (b) $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ may not be symmetric about $y=x$ 
>   (c) $f(x)$ may not be odd 
>   (d) none of these

For function to be odd $f(x)=-f(-x)$ and I have taken a point with coordinate $(a,b)$ then its reflections in $y=-x$ ,it's new coordinate is $(-b,-a)$ and both coordinate are satisfied by $y=x^3$ which is an odd so option a is correct.

Can you tell is it correct or suggest any better approach?

Comment: Is (a) necessary? The Q is which, if any , of (a),(b),(c) are $implied$ by the conditions.

Comment: My edit was for a trivial typo.

Comment: I do some correction see it

Comment: Still lots of ambiguity here.  In HK Lee's answer, the phrase "may not be odd" is used in the sense "is not necessarily odd", meaning might or might not be odd.  But "may not be odd" could also mean "not allowed to be odd", which is equivalent to "must not be odd".  It is very hard to tell which sense is being used here.  A second ambiguity: I originally interpreted the condition that "$f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ are symmetric about" a line as meaning that the graph of $f$ is symmetric about that line and so is the graph of $f^{-1}$.  But it then occurred to me that the question asker might have...

Comment: ...been (somewhat imprecisely) saying that the graph of $f^{-1}$ is the image under reflection about the line of the graph of $f$.  Then I read HK Lee's answer, where the phrase is interpreted in a manner the includes both of these possibilities, and others as well, namely that the union of the graphs of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ is symmetric about the line.  As HK Lee notes, this question was asked a few years back, formulated in exactly the same words.  So both you and the previous asker must be quoting from a common source.  Can you say what that source is?

Comment: I just noticed that the other question HK Lee mentioned differs from yours in choice (b).  That question says “may not be symmetric” whereas yours says “may be symmetric”.  As you have it, choice (b) is a true statement since the symmetry holds for the identity function $f(x)=x$, irrespective of the interpretational ambiguity I mentioned.  Could you double check the wording, and also identify the source of the question?

Comment: Yes there should be some correction in option b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to reformulate the question and then answer the reformulated question.  If this reformulation does not capture what the original question asker intended, then my answer may not be so useful.

> Let $f$ be an invertible function such the the graph of $f^{-1}$ is the image of the graph of $f$ under reflection about the line $y=-x$.  Then
>   (a) $f$ is odd
>   (b) the graph of $f^{-1}$ is not necessarily the image of the graph of $f$ under reflection about the line $y=x$
>   (c) $f$ is not necessarily odd
>   (d) none of these

To say that $(x,y)$ is on the graph of $f$ is to say that $y=f(x)$.  By assumption, if $(x,y)$ is on the graph of $f$, then $(-y,-x)$ is on the graph of $f^{-1}$, which is to say, $-x=f^{-1}(-y)$.  Applying the function $f$ to both sides yields $f(-x)=-y$.  Therefore, if $f(x)=y$ then $f(-x)=-y$.  So $f$ is an odd function, which is choice (a).

Since choice (a) is correct, it is clear that choices (c) and (d) are incorrect.  Any invertible function $f$ is going to have the property that the graph of $f^{-1}$ is the image of the graph of $f$ under reflection about the line $y=x$.  So (b) is manifestly incorrect.

Your attempt verified (a) for the particular example $f(x)=x^3$.  While this example is illustrative, it cannot by itself prove a general statement.

Answer (score 1):

There are similar question in

[1] [Will this function be odd?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1777805/will-this-function-be-odd?rq=1)

[2] kennytm's comment

**Def :** $f$ and $g$ are symmetric wrt a line $l\ :\ y=ax+b$ if ${\rm
graph}\ f\bigcup {\rm graph}\ g$ is invariant under a reflection wrt
the
line $l$

**EXE :** If $f:R\rightarrow R $ is an invertible function
such that $f(x)$ and $ f^{-1}(x)$ are symmetric about the line $y=-x
$, then $f$ may not be odd

**Proof :** $A =(x,f(x)), \ B=(y,f^{-1}(y))$ s.t. $\frac{A+B}{2}$ is in
line $y=x$

By an assumption, $-A,\ -B$ are points in $f$ and $f^{-1}$. When
$-A$ is in ${\rm graph}\ f$, then $f$ is odd.

When $-B$ is in ${\rm graph}\ f$, then we have an example (**cf**. [2]) : $$f(x)=2x,\ x>0\ {\rm and
}\ f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x,\ x\leq 0$$